# Using callable params to modify a query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using [`craftable`](https://github.com/BRACKETS-by-TRIAD/craftable) to generate an admin panel for my app.

I have an Organisation model that belongs to an Organisation Type model.

In the index listing, I want to be able to display the Organisation Type name rather than the _id. To do this, I have to modify this query, to eager load the relationship using the 'with' method.

The method signature for the listing is:

```
public static function processRequestAndGet($request, $columns = array(), $searchIn = null, $modifyQuery = null, $locale = null)
```

and the index method is:

```
$data = AdminListing::create(Organisation::class)->processRequestAndGet(
        // pass the request with params
            $request,

            // set columns to query
            ['id', 'organisation_type_id', 'name', 'active'],

            // set columns to searchIn
            ['id', 'name']
        );

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return ['data' => $data];
        }

        return view('admin.organisation.index', ['data' => $data]);
```

Craftable, provides a modifyQuery method to, but i'm not sure how to use it:

```
public function index(IndexMovie $request)
    {
        $data = AdminListing::create(Movie::class)
            ->modifyQuery(function($query) use ($request){
                if ($request->has('author_id')) {
                    $query->where('author_id', $request->author_id);
                }
            })
            ->get();
```

Can someone help me use the callback to modify the query so that I can include the related table data?

Comment: Please elaborate your question it is not clear

Comment: I still can't understand your need man what errors are you getting what do u want to do  not clear with anything :(

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better than I already have... the processRequestAndGet method takes another method as a parameter... so that the Underlying query can be modified. I'd like some advice on how this can be accomplished

Comment: sorry i am not able to help you buddy if i get something like this i will surely update

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I've came across the exact same problem and I'd like to share my way of doing it.

[`craftable`](https://github.com/BRACKETS-by-TRIAD/craftable) uses a `processRequestAndGet` function that takes as a 4th parametre the intended callable query. So when you need to use that parametre rather than trying to access the `modifyQuery` function directly.

```
$data_r = AdminListing::create(Organisation::class)
    ->processRequestAndGet(
        // pass the request with params
        $request,

        // set columns to query
        ['id', 'organisation_type_id', 'name', 'active'],

        // set columns to searchIn
        ['id', 'name'],

        function($query) use ($request){
            if ($request->has('author_id')) {
                $query->where('author_id', $request->author_id);
            }
        }
    );
```

You were almost right, just pass the intended callback inside your `processRequestAndGet` and voilà.